# What does the name shown beside the question infer?

Tags: support

Under the Questions section of my account i see that for this particular [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83413/why-is-my-stock-widget-not-displaying-anything-displays-problem-loading-widget) with a time stamp and a different name Darshar Parikh.On clicking the question there's again my account name displayed below the question

[image]
[image]

I have checked various questions and i come to know that it usually displays the person who has answered or commented on the Post.But for this specific question the displayed name has neither posted an answer nor posted any comment then why is this name being displayed.
Could you please tell me what exactly the name displayed by the question infer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant by this,

[image]

It actually shows the last activity on that post, excluding the deletion.

Most possibly, here is the actual timeline:

- You asked the question on Sep 26
- You edited it on Sep 29 at 6:03
- Darshak Parikh answered it on Sep 29 at 6:43
- The community & moderators found out that his post was not really an answer to the question, thus deleted it. (This didn't change the last activity time)

Hence, it shows Darshak Parikh's answer as the last activity.

Comment: what is taken to reflect on the page with regard to the remaining questions.

Comment: To put it simply, the last activity on that post (new answer posted, question edited, answer edited) before it is deleted.

Comment: thanks for the clarification i understood that it's the last activity on that post then why didn't the activity refreshed when the post got deleted as compared with the remaining posts

Comment: For that precise case, I cannot answer because I'm not SE staff :) There are quite many similar posts like this on [meta.se]. Looking from [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/incorrect-last-activity-user) question, it seems it's status by design though.

Comment: ok i see that the user has for wanted replied the post in order to gain rep as the user is having only 1 rep that too given by Android SE